# ¿Cómo reproducir un stream y mp3 a la vez?

Tags: javascript, audio, radio, mp3

Tengo el siguiente código:

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Simple Music Player</title>
      <!-- Load FontAwesome icons -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">

      <!-- CSS style -->
      <style>
        body {
          background-color: lightgreen;
    <body>
      <div class="player">
        <div class="details">
          <div class="now-playing">PLAYING x OF y</div>
          <div class="track-art"></div>
          <div class="track-name">Track Name</div>
          <div class="track-artist">Track Artist</div>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
          <div class="prev-track" onclick="prevTrack()"><i class="fa fa-step-backward fa-2x"></i></div>
          <div class="playpause-track" onclick="playpauseTrack()"><i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-5x"></i></div>
          <div class="next-track" onclick="nextTrack()"><i class="fa fa-step-forward fa-2x"></i></div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider_container">
          <div class="current-time">00:00</div>
          <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="0" class="seek_slider" onchange="seekTo()">
          <div class="total-duration">00:00</div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider_container">
          <i class="fa fa-volume-down"></i>
          <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="99" class="volume_slider" onchange="setVolume()">
          <i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Main script for the player -->
      <script>
        let now_playing = document.querySelector(".now-playing");
        let track_art = document.querySelector(".track-art");
        let track_name = document.querySelector(".track-name");
        let track_artist = document.querySelector(".track-artist");

        let playpause_btn = document.querySelector(".playpause-track");
        let next_btn = document.querySelector(".next-track");
        let prev_btn = document.querySelector(".prev-track");

        let seek_slider = document.querySelector(".seek_slider");
        let volume_slider = document.querySelector(".volume_slider");
        let curr_time = document.querySelector(".current-time");
        let total_duration = document.querySelector(".total-duration");

        let track_index = 0;
        let isPlaying = false;
        let updateTimer;

        // Create new audio element
        let curr_track = document.createElement('audio');

        // Define the tracks that have to be played
        let track_list = [
          {
            name: "Night Owl",
            artist: "Broke For Free",
            image: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/2264753/pexels-photo-2264753.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=250&w=250",
            path: "https://files.freemusicarchive.org/storage-freemusicarchive-org/music/WFMU/Broke_For_Free/Directionless_EP/Broke_For_Free_-_01_-_Night_Owl.mp3"
          },
          {
            name: "Enthusiast",
            artist: "Tours",
            image: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3100835/pexels-photo-3100835.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=250&w=250",
            path: "https://files.freemusicarchive.org/storage-freemusicarchive-org/music/no_curator/Tours/Enthusiast/Tours_-_01_-_Enthusiast.mp3"
          },
          {
            name: "Shipping Lanes",
            artist: "Chad Crouch",
            image: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1717969/pexels-photo-1717969.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=250&w=250",
            path: "https://files.freemusicarchive.org/storage-freemusicarchive-org/music/ccCommunity/Chad_Crouch/Arps/Chad_Crouch_-_Shipping_Lanes.mp3",
          },
        ];

        function loadTrack(track_index) {
          clearInterval(updateTimer);
          resetValues();

          // Load a new track
          curr_track.src = track_list[track_index].path;
          curr_track.load();

          // Update details of the track
          track_art.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + track_list[track_index].image + ")";
          track_name.textContent = track_list[track_index].name;
          track_artist.textContent = track_list[track_index].artist;
          now_playing.textContent = "PLAYING " + (track_index + 1) + " OF " + track_list.length;

          // Set an interval of 1000 milliseconds for updating the seek slider
          updateTimer = setInterval(seekUpdate, 1000);

          // Move to the next track if the current one finishes playing
          curr_track.addEventListener("ended", nextTrack);

          // Apply a random background color
          random_bg_color();
        }

        function random_bg_color() {

          // Get a random number between 64 to 256 (for getting lighter colors)
          let red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + 64;
          let green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + 64;
          let blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + 64;

          // Construct a color withe the given values
          let bgColor = "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")";

          // Set the background to that color
          document.body.style.background = bgColor;
        }

        // Reset Values
        function resetValues() {
          curr_time.textContent = "00:00";
          total_duration.textContent = "00:00";
          seek_slider.value = 0;
        }

        function playpauseTrack() {
          if (!isPlaying) playTrack();
          else pauseTrack();
        }

        function playTrack() {
          curr_track.play();
          isPlaying = true;

          // Replace icon with the pause icon
          playpause_btn.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-pause-circle fa-5x"></i>';
        }

        function pauseTrack() {
          curr_track.pause();
          isPlaying = false;

          // Replace icon with the play icon
          playpause_btn.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-5x"></i>';;
        }

        function nextTrack() {
          if (track_index < track_list.length - 1)
            track_index += 1;
          else track_index = 0;
          loadTrack(track_index);
          playTrack();
        }

        function prevTrack() {
          if (track_index > 0)
            track_index -= 1;
          else track_index = track_list.length;
          loadTrack(track_index);
          playTrack();
        }

        function seekTo() {
          seekto = curr_track.duration * (seek_slider.value / 100);
          curr_track.currentTime = seekto;
        }

        function setVolume() {
          curr_track.volume = volume_slider.value / 100;
        }

        function seekUpdate() {
          let seekPosition = 0;

          // Check if the current track duration is a legible number
          if (!isNaN(curr_track.duration)) {
            seekPosition = curr_track.currentTime * (100 / curr_track.duration);
            seek_slider.value = seekPosition;

            // Calculate the time left and the total duration
            let currentMinutes = Math.floor(curr_track.currentTime / 60);
            let currentSeconds = Math.floor(curr_track.currentTime - currentMinutes * 60);
            let durationMinutes = Math.floor(curr_track.duration / 60);
            let durationSeconds = Math.floor(curr_track.duration - durationMinutes * 60);

            // Adding a zero to the single digit time values
            if (currentSeconds < 10) { currentSeconds = "0" + currentSeconds; }
            if (durationSeconds < 10) { durationSeconds = "0" + durationSeconds; }
            if (currentMinutes < 10) { currentMinutes = "0" + currentMinutes; }
            if (durationMinutes < 10) { durationMinutes = "0" + durationMinutes; }

            curr_time.textContent = currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds;
            total_duration.textContent = durationMinutes + ":" + durationSeconds;
          }
        }

        // Load the first track in the tracklist
        loadTrack(track_index);
      </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Funciona genial el reproductor, y lo que deseo hacer es que cuando se haga clic en Play, también se cargue un archivo mp3 donde tengo una voz en off que se escucharía sobre la radio, como una marca de agua.

El código que me pasaron es este:

```html
<script>
    var aud2  = new Audio();
    aud2.loop = true; // reproducir en bucle
    var src = document.createElement("source");
    src.type = "audio/mpeg";
    src.src  = "https://sitio.com/radio/voice.mp3"
    aud2.appendChild(src);

    document.getElementById("miaudio").onplay = function(){
        aud2.play()
    };
    document.getElementById("miaudio").onpause = function(){
        aud2.pause();
    };
</script>
```

Los agrego juntos pero no puedo lograr que funcione. Necesito que se active el mp3 cuando se escuche las emisoras de radio.

El código original del reproductor está **[aquí](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/online-html-editor/T3gdWUn4aX)**.